# How to put RelativeLayout inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-relativelayout, android-support-design

I'm trying to recreate the search box as it is in Airbnb Android app.
So I'm using **CoorinatorLayout** with **Toolbar** and **RecyclerView**.

But when I insert something inside the Coordinator besides those two things, it doesn't show up. 
Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slidingLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:hint="Unesite grad"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancelSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

But actually if this even worked, I would have the trouble of putting the search box above the RecyclerView.

I have tried to put everything inside the **RelativeLayout** but that didn't work.

Here is also the picture of what I'm trying to make
[image]

EDIT:

Here is the code with RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:id="@+id/appbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
           android:background="#00000000">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:background="@color/red"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:padding="6dp"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/search"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="6"
              android:background="@null"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
              android:hint="Unesite grad"
              android:paddingLeft="16dp"
              android:paddingStart="16dp" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/cancelSearch"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you *tried* to put the `RelativeLayout` in the `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: I tried it 2 ways. First I was wrapping all the views inside of the CoordinatorLayout so the Relative was the first and only child. That resulted in loosing the scroll behavior on all the elements. And the other one is in the EDIT, where I wrapped the RecyclerView and this search box inside the Relative.

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic Scroll behavior will work to all child that are direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`, so if you set layout behavior to the `RelativeLayout` nested scrolling will work.

Answer (score 28):

I was trying to do something a little similar, but with an ad banner at the bottom of the screen. My solution was to wrap the `RelativeLayout` outside the `CoordinatorLayout` as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/ad_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
      app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
      app:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The toolbar properly hides when scrolling inside the `RecyclerView` and everything seems to be working just fine. I would imagine if you followed a similar principle you should be good-to-go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove status bar white colour, you must remove the next line

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`
```

in `v21/styles.xml`

Thanks for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:hint="Unesite grad"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cancelSearch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Check if this works for you.