# View covering action toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-relativelayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to create a tool bar associated with an `EditText` on my scren. Below are the contents of my xml file that I am trying to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tool:context=".CreatePost"
    android:id="@+id/create_post">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/create_post_toolbar"/>

    <!-- Edit text for typing status. Light gray placeholder. -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
        android:layout_below="@id/create_post_toolbar"
        android:hint="Update your friends!"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:id="@+id/type_status"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`app_bar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".CreatePost">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar_universal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, when I do this, my `EditText` covers my toolbar. Here is an image to show what happens:

[image: Image showing screen]

I don't really understand why this is happening, is there anyway to align my `EditText` so it doesn't cover the toolbar? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: after adding in Arya's code into mine, my image looks like so, which makes the `ActionBar` too high. Any ideas on how to fix it?

[image: Action bar too high]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout, in its current definition, does not make much sense. I think the problem here is that the `CoordinatorLayout` has been assigned `fitsSystemWindows=true`. This makes it report its `bottom` from the very top of the status-bar. On the other hand, the `RelativeLayout` expects the `bottom` value from the bottom of the status-bar. This makes your `EditText` overlap the `Toolbar` by `25dp` - the standard height of a status-bar. You can kind of confirm this by assigning `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `RelativeLayout` with id `create_post`. In this case, the `bottom` for `CoordinatorLayout` will be reported correctly, and the `EditText` will *not* overlap the `Toolbar`.

Usually, the `CoordinatorLayout` is set to be the parent, and the content (in your case the `RelativeLayout`) resides as a child of the `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".CreatePost">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_universal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/create_post">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
            android:hint="Update your friends!"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:id="@+id/type_status"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you have a specific reason for placing the `CoordinatorLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`, please do share.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. I appreciate all your help! :) just one question: I have an `AppBarLayout` in most if not all of my activities. I see in this answer that you provided the `AppBarLayout` directly in the file instead of putting it into another file where I can just do `<include layout="@layout/app_bar">`. In my context I can't include the `app_bar.xml` in every file and have the layout like this so I would have to declare it in every file that uses it then?

Comment: Also, is it wrong to put a `CoordinatorLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`? I see on a few examples like so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33452360/1871869 that people HAVE put it in. What are the reasons for actually doing so?

Comment: @user1871869 No, you can still use `<include />` - but only for `<AppBarLayout><Toolbar></Toolbar></AppBarLayout>`. So, your setup will look something like this: `<CoordinatorLayout><include layout="@layout/appbar"><include layout="ACTUAL_CONTENT"></CoordinatorLayout>`. I hope this is legible enough. BUT, I do see your point, and unfortunately, `<CoordinatorLayout>` will have to be put in every layout file.

Comment: @user1871869 Well, apart from the problem you just faced placing `CoordinatorLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`, the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) points out the primary use-cases: #1 is how I have always used a `CoordinatorLayout`. #2 kind of implies that placing it inside another container _should_ work. But I haven't done that myself. So, its not _wrong_ per se. Perhaps, removing the `fitsSystemWindows` attribute when placing `CoordinatorLayout` inside another `ViewGroup` is all that's required.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/tabheader"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"> 
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>         
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, the action bar now shows up properly without being hidden by the `EditText` but now the action bar is too high. I have updated my post above to show what it looks like now. Is there anyway to fix this? And I would prefer not to use `app:titleMarginTop="13dp"` either. Thanks!

Comment: That did not fix it. It is exactly the same as it was above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```